# Should I disable systemd-timesyncd if ntp is installed?

Tags: ntp, systemd-timesyncd

Is there any issue with running `systemd-timesyncd` and `ntp` on the same machine?

I'm asking this because I have started using `NTP` on all servers but the `systemd-timesyncd` is running there as well. Should I disable it? Any issues with both running?

Answer (score 2):

It shouldn't be necessary to disable `systemd-timesyncd` if you install `ntp`, because the `ntp` service configuration includes the following:

```
# grep -i conflict /lib/systemd/system/ntp.service 
Conflicts=systemd-timesyncd.service
```

The same applies for the `chrony` service on newer Ubuntu versions.

There have been startup bugs in the past which meant `systemd-timesyncd` tried to adjust the clock while another NTP server is running, producing harmless-but-annoying errors in the system logs.  So there should be no harm in disabling `systemd-timesyncd` if that's what you prefer.

Comment: In my case, though, I often see `ntp` not started on a reboot. (from what I know, that happens when port 123 is already in use). So there must be some sort of side effect...

Comment: When that happens, grab your `systemctl status ntp.service` output straight after boot to confirm.  But again, there have been startup bugs in the past which should be long-fixed by now if your packages are up-to-date. I haven't seen NTP fail to start on boot for a long time.